# What happens if you get to The End on peaceful?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just wondered, what happens if you get to The End on peaceful?

The mobs always disappear on peaceful, so what happens with the enderdragon and such?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As John pointed out in the comments, you'll need to play on a difficult other than peaceful to collect the ingredients needed for the Eyes of Ender that are used in the creation of an End Portal. Of course, you can always switch to peaceful before going to the End or "hack" in Eyes of Ender, so the question is legitimate.

As one might expect, setting the difficult to peaceful prevents any Endermen from spawning. However, the Ender Dragon is still present and behaves in the same way.

Comment: Could you not find ender pearls in underground chests and trade them with a priest to get enough eyes of ender?

Comment: Afaict that was possible pre 1.8 but not in current versions. Afaict the only way to get to the end in current versions in peaceful survival is to use a selected seed.

Answer (score 7):

The Ender Dragon actually does appear in the peaceful difficulty. I tested it in Creative mode and Survival mode. You actually don't need to go into a difficulty other than peaceful.  You can trade 7-13 emeralds with for 1 Eye of Ender with a Priest Villager. That is the easiest way to go if you are in Survival with no cheats allowed.

Comment: I can confirm I have just done this as well. I played in Peaceful/Survival mode only and was able to trade for all the Eyes of Ender I needed. I had to expand the village a bit and do a bit of work, but I was able to get to the End and be killed by the Enderdragon.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your game on peaceful cheats, you can switch from creative to survival, so you could just get a stack of ender eyes, and switch out to survival.

Anyway, I've tried it, and the ender dragon is there, but no enderman.