# Can you still earn the ender dragon achievement in peaceful mode on PS4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

Update ID: v1.18.31 (bottom right of main menu)

Mode: Survival, Peaceful; never has been set to Creative. But has been temporarily switched to easy, medium, or hard to kill endermen and blaze(s).

Background:

- Other achievements can be earned on peaceful mode (example: the wool achievement)
- No achievements can be earned on creative mode or a save file previously set to creative at any point

Question: Will you get the ender dragon achievement if you kill it on peaceful mode? (Has never been set to creative)

Answer (score 2):

While the Ender Dragon [does apparently spawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70415/what-happens-if-you-get-to-the-end-on-peaceful#:%7E:text=The%20Ender%20Dragon%20actually%20does,Ender%20with%20a%20Priest%20Villager.) in Peaceful mode, you won't be able to get there without extreme luck, as the only way to obtain Eyes of Ender is by killing Blazes for the Blaze Powder. The only way to access the End in Peaceful would require the right seed:

> if you are extraordinarily lucky, or have the seed, there is a very small chance that every spot on the Ender Portal will be already filled with Eyes of Ender, because there is a chance that some Eyes of Ender will already be filled in.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-kill-the-Ender-Dragon-in-peaceful-mode)

So since the Dragon does apparently spawn, killing it would grant the Achievement to you.